# Proper way to fetch from another component - ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch, fetch-api

I have a component that fetches the data properly but I want to encapsulate it in a helper. I've tried many things but I'm stuck.

This is the component that works:

```
export const Carousel = () => {

const [ lotteries, setLotteries ] = useState({});
const [ isLoading, setisLoading ] = useState(true);

useEffect(() => {
    
    async function fetchAPI() {
        const url = 'https://protected-sea-30988.herokuapp.com/https://www.lottoland.com/api/drawings;'
        let response = await fetch(url)
        response = await response.json()
        
        setLotteries(response)
        setisLoading(false)
        }
    
        fetchAPI()
}, [])

return (

    <>
        {
            isLoading ? (
                <span>loading</span>
            ) : (

            <Slider >
                {
                Object.keys(lotteries).map((lottery, idx) => {
                    return (
                        <Slide 
                            key={ idx }
                            title={ lottery }
                            prize={ lotteries[lottery].next.jackpot }
                            day={ lotteries[lottery].next.date.day }
                        />
                    )
                })
                }
            </Slider>
        )}
    </>
);}
```

And this is the last thing I've tried so far. This is the component without the fetch

```
export const Carousel = () => {

const [ lotteries, setLotteries ] = useState({});
const [ isLoading, setIsLoading ] = useState(true);

useEffect(() => {
    
    getLotteries()
    setLotteries(response)
    setIsLoading(false)
      
}, [])
```

And this is where I tried to encapsulate the fetching.

```
export const getLotteries = async() => {

    const url = 'https://protected-sea-30988.herokuapp.com/https://www.lottoland.com/api/drawings;'
    let response = await fetch(url)
    response = await response.json()

    return response;
    
}
```

I'm a bit new to React, so any help would be much appreciated. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the fetched data from getLotteries helper you have to return a promise

```
export const getLotteries = async() => {
const url = 'https://protected-sea- 
 30988.herokuapp.com/https://www.lottoland.com/api/drawings;'
let response = await fetch(url)
return  response.json()
```

}

and call it as async/await

```
useEffect(async() => {

let response= await getLotteries()
setLotteries(response)
setIsLoading(false)

}, [])
```

Comment: that works! even though it throws a warning now 
"Effect callbacks are synchronous to prevent race conditions. Put the async function inside:

useEffect(() => {
  async function fetchData() {
    // You can await here
    const response = await MyAPI.getData(someId);
    // ...
  }
  fetchData();
}, [someId]); // Or [] if effect doesn't need props or state
"
So finally asking to get all the fetch inside the component instead of the helper. :(

Comment: Finally i could avoid it editing your useEffect like in my answer below.

Comment: useEffect(() => {

        const fetchLotteries = async () => {
            const data = await getLotteries();
            setLotteries(data);
            setIsLoading(false)
        }

        fetchLotteries();
        
    }, [])

Answer (score 1):

If you want to separate the logic for requesting a URL into another helper function, you can create a custom hook.

```js
// customHook.js

import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

export function useLotteries() {
  const [lotteries, setLotteries] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch('https://protected-sea-30988.herokuapp.com/https://www.lottoland.com/api/drawings;')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(json => setLotteries(json));
  }, []);

  return lotteries;
}

// Carousel.js

import { useLotteries } from "./customHook.js";

export const Carousel = () => {
  const lotteries = useLotteries();

  if (lotteries) {
    return; /* Your JSX here! (`lotteries` is now contains all the request responses) */
  } else {
    return <Loader />; // Or just null if you don't want to show a loading indicator when your data hasn't been received yet.
  }
};
```

Comment: I've tried that out but it throws "TypeError: Object is not iterable"
:(

Comment: @Serralvaro the newer code should work

Comment: Many thanks @ Saiansh Singh

Comment: Thank you for this answer, it solved my issue without using any extra libs. Nice!